# REGEX in PHP to validate name and surname

Tags: php, regex, validation, input

I'm trying to validate name and surname with preg_match, but there's something wrong in my function.

I want allow all types of name or surname (or name) like:

Surname
S'urname
Sur-name
Sur name

But also 2 or more surname in 1 string (or name) like

Surnameone Surnametwo Surnamethree

I'm trying with this REGEX, I searched and found other solutions, but with a surname like "O'Hara" it doesn't match.

```
$nameValidation = "/^[a-zA-Z '-]*$/";
$surname=filter_var($_POST['surname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (preg_match($nameValidation, $surname)) {
    echo 'VALID ' . $surname;
} else {
    echo 'NOT VALID ' . $surname;
}
```

I send the input with ajax call

```
'surname': $.trim($('#floatingInputSurname').val()),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If someone is trying to enter crap data and you disallow certain characters, the person will still enter crap just in the syntax you want it to be. I'd simply use `strlen() >= 2` as a filter and keep things simple. The trick that makes people submit their correct data is to make it actually useful to enter correct data.

Comment: Remove `filter_var`, it'll work. When you using regex with strictly defined chars to testing variable value, `filter_var` isn't necessary.

Comment: If you had dumped the value of `$surname`, you would have seen that it's actually `O&#39;Hara` (the result of `filter_var`). Debugging is a crucial skill in the programming world and you might start with learning the [basics](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/) and later, when you're more comfortable, you can [learn more](https://stackify.com/php-debugging-guide/).